# Hi I am new to rust And I tried to setup a matrix rust server... and it always throws me a issue in error.rs

Tags: matrix, rust, build-error, conduit

```
error[E0599]: no method named `map_err` found for type parameter `Self` in the current scope
  --> src\server\error.rs:40:24
   |
34 | pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized {
   | ----------------------------- method `map_err` not found for this type parameter
...
40 |         let res = self.map_err(|_| MatrixError::internal_err());
   |                        ^^^^^^^ method not found in `Self`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the type parameter is bounded by the trait
help: the following traits define an item `map_err`, perhaps you need to add another supertrait for one of them:
   |
34 | pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized + ServiceFactory {
   |                               ++++++++++++++++
34 | pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized + TryFutureExt {
   |                               ++++++++++++++
34 | pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized + TryStreamExt {
   |                               ++++++++++++++
34 | pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized + actix_service::Service {
   |                               ++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
warning: `maelstrom` (bin "maelstrom") generated 12 warnings
error: could not compile `maelstrom` due to previous error; 12 warnings emitted
```

It runs into an error where it says that `self.map_err` is not defined

I tried to completely delete the `error.rs` out of the code (it didn't work)

here is the code to mess around with
(oh and yes the matrix server uses actix web)

```
use actix_web::{http::StatusCode, Error, HttpResponse};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct MatrixError {
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub status: StatusCode,
    pub errcode: ErrorCode,
    pub error: String,
}

impl MatrixError {
    pub fn new(status: StatusCode, errcode: ErrorCode, error: &str) -> Self {
        MatrixError {
            status,
            errcode,
            error: error.to_string(),
        }
    }

    pub fn internal_err() -> Self {
        Self::new(
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ErrorCode::UNKNOWN,
            "Internal server error.",
        )
    }
}
impl From<MatrixError> for Error {
    fn from(e: MatrixError) -> Self {
        HttpResponse::build(e.status).json(e).into()
    }
}

pub trait ResultExt<T>: Sized {
    fn with_codes(self, status: StatusCode, code: ErrorCode) -> Result<T, MatrixError>;
    fn unknown(self) -> Result<T, MatrixError> {
        #[cfg(debug_assertions)] // don't leak ISE info in release mode
        let res = self.with_codes(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ErrorCode::UNKNOWN);
        #[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
        let res = self.map_err(|_| MatrixError::internal_err());
        res
    }
}

impl<T, E> ResultExt<T> for Result<T, E>
where
    E: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn with_codes(self, status: StatusCode, code: ErrorCode) -> Result<T, MatrixError> {
        self.map_err(|e| MatrixError {
            status,
            errcode: code,
            error: format!("{}", e),
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: for reference I am talking about the chat platform matrix

Comment: You can't use `Result::map_err` if you don't know that you have a `Result` which you don't since anything could implement `ResultExt`.

Comment: Try moving the implementation of the `unknown` function from the trait definition to the trait implementation. That way, the compiler knows which type you are calling the `map_err` function on